# MySQL не принимает название столбца, если оно задано PHP-переменной

Tags: php, mysql

Всем добрый день. 
Почему не работает такая конструкция? Если вместо пост-имя подставить name, то все в порядке. POST содержит точно такую же name.

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE `backend` SET '" . $_POST['name'] . "' = '" . $_POST['update'] . "' WHERE `id` = '" . $_POST['id'] . "'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените Ваши одинарные кавычки на `, там где указываете имя таблицы или столбца. Например так:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE `backend` SET `" . $_POST['name'] . "` = '" .
 $_POST['update'] . "' WHERE `id` = '" . $_POST['id'] . "'");
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало, а ведь я пробовал добавлять  ` , правда оборачивал и одинарные и двойные